# How to animate TextSpans within Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a project that requires minor **animations** to text as it appears in a `TextFormField`.

I hav extended the `TextEditingControler` and overriden the `buildTextSpan` function to enable different `TextSyles` based on the types of words that were being typed in. For example if a word is `['the','a','me']`.

For example I would add a `TextSpan` with a particular style for each matching word and for all other words I would just add the word in a `TextSpan` with normal style.

This is working fine, however, what I want to do is to **animate the matched words for a period as they are entered**, for example they would turn from blue to green.

**Extended TextEditingController Class**

```
class RichTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {

  TextStyle matchedStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.green,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  );

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({TextStyle style, bool withComposing}) {
    List<String> wordsToMatchList = ['the','a','me'];

    List<String> splitText = text.split(' ');
    List<TextSpan> textSpanList = [];

    splitText.forEach((word) {
      if (wordsToMatchList.contains(word)) {
        textSpanList.add(TextSpan(style: boldStyle, text: '$word'));
      } else {
        textSpanList.add(TextSpan(style: style, text: '$word'));
      }
    });

    return TextSpan(children: textSpanList);
  }
}
```

I have tried various techniques like future.Delayed and others, but can't seem to find any approach that works and need some help.

**Question: Is there a way to add a minor animation to TextSpans or other widgets that would show when new text is typed into a text field that matches a certain pattern?**

Comment: start with https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qy5PKzFNWV/ - notice it works only once ;-( since i have no idea how and when to trigger `animationController.forward` method (line #71)

Comment: Thanks @pskink I will try it out today.

Comment: @pskink How does this work, currently I am seperating via ' '. : pattern = RegExp(mapping.keys.map((key) => RegExp.escape(key)).join('|'));